# Descomponer una variable que contiene HTML

Tags: html, jquery

hola buenas tengo una consulta como puedo descomponer una variable que contiene lo siguiente

```
    <div>
        <strong>titulo aqui</strong>
        <br>
        <text>Texto aqui</text>
    </div>
```

Lo que me gustaria es poder obtener el contenido del strong en una variable y el contenido del text en otra sin las etiquetas html

```
var titulo = titulo aqui

var text = Texto aqui
```

existe alguna forma?

Answer (score 1):

La idea de lo que buscas seria que los textos se encuentren dentro de alguna etiqueta con algún id para obtener el valor con JQuery (en el caso que lo estés usando) y almacenarlo en las variables como lo pedís. seria algo como esto:

```
    <div>
        <strong id='titulo'>titulo aqui</strong>
        <br>
        <text id='texto'>Texto aqui</text>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var titulo = $('#titulo').text();
        var texto = $('#texto').text();
        console.log(titulo);
        console.log(texto);
    </script>
```

Los *console.log()* son para que compruebes que las variables contienen el valor de las etiquetas.

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo la alternativa con JS puro.

No tienes más que usar [getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp) y coger el primer elemento del `array`. Ten en cuenta que esto te valdría sólo en caso de tener un elemento `<strong>` y un elemento `<text>`. Si tuvieras más tendrías que recorrer el `array` e ir haciendo el tratamiento correspondiente.

```js
let strongTag = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0];
let textTag = document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0];
console.log(strongTag.innerText);
console.log(textTag.innerText);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<strong>titulo aqui</strong>
<br>
<text>Texto aqui</text>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando jQuery no es algo complejo, podes usar `jQuery(''selector'')`.

```js
//Defino una variable con el contenido de tu ejemplo
var html =   "<div>"+
              "<strong>titulo aqui</strong>"+
              "<br>"+
              "<text>Texto aqui</text>"+
            "</div>";

//Obtengo el texto de la etiqueta strong dentro de la variable html
var Titulo = jQuery('strong',html).text();
//Obtengo el texto de la etiqueta text dentro de la variable html
var Text = jQuery('text',html).text();

//Muestro el resultado
console.log(Titulo);
console.log(Text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si te estas iniciando en jQuery, sería altamente recomendable [esta](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) lectura, para aprender a usar los selectores, cosa que te va a ayudar un montón!

Comment: Muchas gracias fue de mucha ayuda =)